# Modal logic with MLp as an axiom

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Writing M for 'possibly', L for 'necessarily' and p for a propositional variable, is there a known modal logic which has MLp as an axiom?  I am cognizant that Lewis's S7 has MMp.

Comment: Just $ \diamond \Box p$? Is there more to the axiom?

Comment: That as an axiom, others are allowed!  In particular I'm interested in Lp->p and M~(p->Lp) as the only axioms.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was 'the only other axioms'.